# What percentage of the mass of green plants / algae is carbon?

Tags: botany

Wikipedia says that the human body is about 18% carbon, but I can't find any percentage on how much of green plants / leaves or algae is carbon? I assume it varies, so if an example is needed, what percent (by mass) of duckweed or grass is carbon?

Comment: Why do you care?  Context helps us to determine whether questions are worth answering.

Comment: I was just interested, some questions get stuck in my head when watching documentaries or reading things. If people do not find the question worth answering, I am afraid my reasons will not make it more worthwhile. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See table 1 [here](https://bg.copernicus.org/articles/15/693/2018/bg-15-693-2018.pdf).

| Life form | reprod organ n | reprod organ mean/sd | root n | root mean/sd | leaf n | leaf mean/sd | stem n | stem mean/sd |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Herbaceous plants | 83 | 42.56± 4.57 | 749 | 42.45± 5.12 | 5181 | 44.73± 3.45 | 162 | 42.41± 3.54 |
| Crop | 42 | 42.40± 5.11 | 56 | 38.20± 5.23 | 85 | 41.32± 3.38 | 69 | 43.26± 3.15 |
| Woody plants | 57 | 48.56± 4.07 | 1392 | 47.43± 3.94 | 12 064 | 47.83± 3.81 | 3461 | 48.16± 3.27 |
| Deciduous broad-leaved | 17 | 46.81± 3.93 | 513 | 46.59± 3.55 | 5074 | 47.25± 3.42 | 1581 | 47.69± 2.68 |
| Evergreen broad-leaved | 29 | 49.64± 4.42 | 520 | 47.72± 4.14 | 4490 | 48.48± 3.86 | 1212 | 47.78± 3.58 |
| Conifers | 8 | 48.25± 2.56 | 252 | 48.43± 4.16 | 560 | 50.25± 3.33 | 502 | 50.48± 3.07 |
| Fern |  |  | 2 | 43.64± 3.83 | 98 | 44.47± 3.33 | – | – |
| Vine | 2 | 45.83± 0.33 | 38 | 46.25± 4.46 | 251 | 45.74± 4.77 | 82 | 46.73± 2.69 |
| Bamboo |  |  | 23 | 45.06± 4.28 | 30 | 42.98± 5.09 | 39 | 49.20± 3.54 |
| All | 142 | 45.01± 5.23 | 2306 | 45.64± 4.95 | 18 124 | 46.85± 3.98 | 3754 | 47.88± 3.49 |

For an algal estimate, see [here](https://agupubs.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1002/2017EF000704):

> Carbon is obtained from the post-carbon-capture flow and compressed to 1 MPa for transport and supply to the growth volume (requiring 248 kJ/kg of gas). Carbon uptake efficiency is 79%. The algal biomass productivity is 82.5 t/ha-yr (23.8 g/m2-d) **with an elemental composition consisting of 48% carbon**, 6.3% nitrogen, and 0.6% phosphorus (Huntley et al., 2015).

Comment: I guess it's not a coincidence that it hovers around 45%, since cellulose is 44% carbon? :) C6H10O5: (6*12.0)/(6*12.0+10*1.0+5*16.0)=0.44

Comment: I guess the issue then becomes how much is cellulose!

Comment: I could not find easily understood numbers on algae? The table was great for anything else, thank you!!

Comment: @HenryStone see edit pulling a direct quote

Comment: @Maximillian Press Thank you for an absolutely excellent answer!